# Is my understanding on this ARM assembly correct? (interrupts and a stack pointer function)

Tags: assembly, arm

```
_get_stack_pointer:
  // Can be called from C
  str     sp, [sp]                  // Store the stack pointer value onto the stack
  ldr     r0, [sp]                  // Load the stack pointer value into r0
  mov     pc, lr                    // Return from function


_enable_interrupts:
  // Can be called from C
  mrs     r0, cpsr                  // Move CPSR into r0
                                    // [C]urrent [P]rogram [S]tatus [R]egister
  mov     r1, #CPSR_IRQ_INHIBIT     // Move CPSR_IRQ_INHIBIT into r1
  bic     r0, r0, r1                // Clear the CPSR_IRQ_INHIBIT bit from CPSR
  msr     cpsr_c, r0                // Move r0 into CPSR
  mov     pc, lr                    // Return from function


_disable_interrupts:
  // Can be called from C
  mrs     r0, cpsr                  // Move CPSR into r0
                                    // [C]urrent [P]rogram [S]tatus [R]egister
  mov     r1, #CPSR_IRQ_INHIBIT     // Move CPSR_IRQ_INHIBIT into r1
  orr     r0, r0, r1                // Set the CPSR_IRQ_INHIBIT bit in CPSR
  msr     cpsr_c, r0                // Move r0 into CPSR
  mov     pc, lr                    // Return from function
```

Comment: no reason to store the stack pointer on the stack simply mov r0,sp; bx lr

Comment: Also, it is cheaper to make an inline `asm` macro to do these things (enable/disable interrupts) as function call overhead is comparatively steep versus the functionality of the routines and probably you want to keep interrupt disabled for a minimum of time.  You should be able to use  ORR/BIC with an immediate.

Comment: [Here is an example from the Linux kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/irqflags.h?h=v4.12-rc3#n66) of `inline` asm to enble/disable interrupts.  Your understanding it *correct*, but how will this help others?